# Make a user able to replace/override a DependencyProperty in my UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` with a `DependencyProperty` defined like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DistanceTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(DistanceText), typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string DistanceText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DistanceTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DistanceTextProperty, value); }
}
```

Somewhere later in this `UserControl` I set the value of the `DependencyProperty` like this:

```
DistanceText = Math.Round((To - From).Length, 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When I'm using this `UserControl` I would like to manually set the `DistanceText` property in `XAML` using a `Binding` like so:

```
<views:MyControl DistanceText="{Binding MyCustomDistanceText}"/>
```

However, because this `DependencyProperty` is already locally set in my `UserControl`, the `Binding` is ignored.

Is there a way to detect in my `UserControl` that the user intents to replace/override the `DependencyProperty` in `XAML`?
I could add a new `DependencyProperty` that the user can set to `true` when he intends to have a custom value, but this is error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a local value, call

```
SetCurrentValue(DistanceTextProperty,
    Math.Round((To - From).Length, 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: If this is called after the value has been changed by the Binding, the value of the Binding is replaced again, is there a way to prevent this? (It does work when the Binding changes after this is called)

Comment: Try [GetBindingExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If `GetBindingExpression` is null, then I can set the `DistanceTextProperty` and otherwise I can just not touch it at all. Works great, thank you.

Comment: Alternatively make the Binding TwoWay.

Comment: It would give more control, but for me it's not needed on the side that's overriding the property.